# Algorithm to find k (k<100) largest differences (by absolute value) from an array of maximum 100 integers

Tags: java, algorithm

If we have an array of integers in a random order (the length N is always < 100), and we are asked to find which k integers (where k < N), when grouped together in an array have the largest sum of all the two-consecutive-term differences by absolute value (which I'll refer to as just SUM), what algorithm would be the fastest to do the task?

E.g: The array 3 1 2 4 3 has a SUM equal to: |(3-1)| + |(1-2)| + |(2-4)| + |(4-3)| = 6.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. What have you tried?

Comment: I was just brainstorming and the only thing I could think of was brute-force computing of all the possible differences which I assume would take a long time.

Comment: Don't assume, just try.

Comment: Dynamic programming gives an easy O(kN^2) algorithm.

Comment: How do you get that?

Comment: If you sorted the array, the greatest values and the least values will be at the end and start respectively. They would also provide the greatest differences and hence the greatest sum. Could that contribute to a solution?

Comment: I was just thinking of the same thing as Jeremy. This is probably the fastest way to get the correct numbers. The solution would run in O(n + (n log n)) = O(n log n), given a good sorting algorithm.